# How can I draw 2 tikz rectangular grids side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-graphdrawing, grids

Here is my MWE. I have the following setup. I want to put a rectangular grid beside X (same size as X) and another(same size as X) to the left of W.

basically. I'm doing Q o X = Q o (W.H) (o is a hadamard product)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        % % % % % Rectangle  
        \draw (.999,-7.5) grid[step=0.5] (3.5,-12.5); % X
     
        \draw (4.499,-7.5) grid[step=0.5] (5.5,-12.5);
        \draw (6.499,-7.5) grid[step=0.5] (9,-8.5);
        \node at (2.25,-7) {$X$};
        \node at (5,-7) {$W$};
        \node at (7.25,-7) {$H$};
        \node at (4,-8) {$\approx$};
        \node at (6,-8) {$\times$};
        \node at (2.25,-13) {Mesures};
            \node at (5,-13) {Scène};
            \node at (7.75,-9) {Paramètres};
        
        \node (calibration_rect1) at (0,-5){};
        \node (calibration_rect2) at (10,-13.5){};
        
        \draw[line width=2pt,rounded corners=1cm] (calibration_rect1) rectangle (calibration_rect2);
         
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

finally I want a layout like this

[image]

Comment: Maybe a little sketch of what you want? It remains unclear to me by reading your description.

Comment: Hello @SebGlav I have added a draft of what im talking about. Q and X should be the same dimensions as in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?
[image]

I'm not sure if the dimensions are right, but as I made a `\pic` for the matrices, it's easy to modify. You can change the dimensions or the positions as you need. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/matrix/.style n args={5}{% rows, columns, text above, text below, text left (or symbol)
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[y=-1cm,scale=0.5]
        \draw    (0,0) grid (#2,#1);
        \node at (0.5*#2,-0.5)   {#3};
        \node at (0.5*#2,#1+0.5) {#4};
        \node at (-0.5,0.5*#1)   {#5};
      \end{scope}     
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \pic at (0,0)    {matrix={10}{5}{$Q$}{}          {}};
  \pic at (3,0)    {matrix={10}{5}{$X$}{}          {$\circ$}};
  \pic at (6,0)    {matrix={10}{5}{$Q$}{Mesures}   {$\approx$}};
  \pic at (9,0)    {matrix={10}{2}{$W$}{Scène}     {$\circ$}};
  \pic at (10.5,0) {matrix= {2}{5}{$H$}{Parameters}{$\times$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** Adding a couple of parentheses, as requested. For this I need another node at the right of the matrices (and another parameter for the `\pic`).

The modified code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/matrix/.style n args={6}{% rows, columns, text above, text below,
                                % text left, text right (or symbols)
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[y=-1cm,scale=0.5]
        \draw    (0,0) grid (#2,#1);
        \node at (0.5*#2,-0.5)   {#3};
        \node at (0.5*#2,#1+0.5) {#4};
        \node at (-0.5,0.5*#1)   {#5};
        \node at (#2+0.5,0.5*#1) {#6};
      \end{scope}     
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \pic at (0,0)   {matrix={10}{5}{$Q$}{}          {}{}};
  \pic at (3,0)   {matrix={10}{5}{$X$}{}          {$\circ$}{}};
  \pic at (6,0)   {matrix={10}{5}{$Q$}{Mesures}   {$\approx$}{$\circ$}};
  \pic at (9.5,0) {matrix={10}{2}{$W$}{Scène}     {}{}};
  \pic at (11,0)  {matrix= {2}{5}{$H$}{Parameters}{$\times$}{}};
  % parentheses
  \filldraw  (9.25,0) to[out=260,in=100]  (9.25,-5) to [out=98,in=262] cycle;
  \filldraw (13.75,0) to[out=-80,in=80]  (13.75,-5) to [out=82,in=-82] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the new output:
[image]

**Note:** of course, if more parentheses were needed it would be probably better to make another `\pic` for them.

Comment: this is excellent. is there a way to enclose the W x H grids in a giant bracket? (W grid x H grid )

Comment: @FaroukYahaya, yes you can draw them too. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. its perfect!

Comment: @FaroukYahaya It is awesome :-)...also. My compliments to Juan Castaño.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano, and Farouk!!